# Right-align broken word ending after hyphenation in RaggedLeft

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyphenation, ragged2e

I have some text that is `RaggedLeft` (that is right-aligned).

If inside that text there is any hyphenated word, the rest of it is left-aligned, like:

```
|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,|
|sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore ma-|
|gna aliqua.                                             |
```

But, **this** is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,|
|sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore ma-|
|                                             gna aliqua.|
```

How is that possible?

Comment: In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown no example, but the usual reason is markup as shown here

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\hyphenpenalty-500 \hyphenation{ma-gna} % to force the hyphenation shown
\begin{document}


\parbox{9.4cm}{{\RaggedLeft
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore ettttt dolore magna aliqua.}}

\bigskip

\parbox{9.4cm}{\RaggedLeft
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore ettttt dolore magna aliqua.}


\end{document}
```

Here the same text is set twice, but in the first case misplaced `{}` cause the scope of the `\RaggedLeft` to end before the paragraph ends so the paragraph is set justified as all the ragged settings are lost at the `}`.